# Embedding a colour picker in Google Forms?

Tags: javascript, html, colors, google-forms, survey

I want to do a survey in which a participant listens to a sound (I link to a Google Drive .mp3 file in the question), then they respond by using an embedded colour picker to drag and choose a specific hex code.

The widget would be similar (if not the same as) the one shown [here](https://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/).

I just want to know how a user would "submit" the colour that they pick.

I don't want to add to many steps as to confuse the participant (as in, go to this colour picker in another tab, type the hex code in this box).

If there's an action I can include to 'submit' their choice, a better survey hosting site (preferably free, please) or a better widget that allows a user to click and drop to a point on the colour spectrum... Please let me know :) thanks!